# Generate html files on remote server, quickly see changes

Tags: macos, sync, html

I'm compiling some rst files on a remote machine to generate html files. I want to view the generated html in my browser to see if it's right, make some changes to the rst, then view them again, etc. I'd like this feedback loop to be as tight as possible. I just started using a Mac, and I'm very new to it. Downloading the html every time is annoying. I was using WinSCP for stuff like this before.

Answer (score 1):

A .rst file is a [reStructuredText](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/rst.html) file. If you generate .html files from that, the remote server should contain the .html files.

I would therefore configure an HTTP server on that machine to serve HTML from whatever folders you are generating .html into. The trick then is to disable caching so that you get to see changes by pressing F5 (or reload).

If you cannot configure an HTTP server, I would consider using something like SSHFS/SAMBA/NFS to share that directory and then browse it using a file:// URL.

Comment: Good suggestions, thanks.  Seems like setting up something like that could be more trouble than it's worth though.  I'm thinking using something like Transmit and just dragging and dropping the html files onto my local machine after every change would be best in terms of cost vs benefit.  Not sure though...